# How to list all subfolders with specific extension tag (eg .jar) at end with numbering order using batch file

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, cmd

The below program gives me output as

**Program Code**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a x=0
(for %%i in (*.apk) do (
 set /a x +=1
 echo !x!^) "%%i"
))>apkmenu.txt

:loop
type apkmenu.txt
set /p "c=Enter your choice: "
if "%c%"=="" goto :loop
if %c% gtr %x% goto :loop
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%i in ('findstr /b "%c%)" apkmenu.txt') do set input=%%j
echo Your file is %input%
```

**Output on screen**

```
1) bla.apk
2) sdss.apk
3) asdads.apk
4) more.apk

Your file is bla.apk (Assuming option 1 was selected)
```

It list all files with .apk extensions
I want to list the folders with .apk in the end. I tried the following -

```
dir /b *.apk|findstr /n "^"
```

but it was no help. It does list folder names but I want only folder name it doesn't give me only folder name.

```
Your file is 1:bla.apk // Output on screen
```

User should be able to choose folders with option like 1, 2 etc.

**User Screen**

```
1) bla.apk  //These are folder names not file
2) sdss.apk
3) asdads.apk
4) more.apk

Enter your choice:
```

**Expected Output**

```
Your file is bla.apk
```

**Real Output**

```
1:bla.apk
```

I want only folder name as output when following code is run

**Code**

```
echo Your file is %input% //Input variable as per seen in above program
```

**Output**

```
Your file is bla.apk
```

I am very sorry for the length of question but I tried to be as precise as I could. Any other ideas/ways or suggestions, will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Change your original code as

```
(for /d %%i in (*.apk) ....
```

The `/d` switch indicates that the `for` command will iterate over directories